# How can I get and set the 'read-only' property of an edit box?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6, cedit

How can I get and set the 'read-only' property of an edit box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `CEdit` class has a [`SetReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa279328(VS.60).aspx) method which can be called at run-time. Latest documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=msvc-170&devlangs=cpp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(AFXWIN%252FCEdit%253A%253ASetReadOnly)%3Bk(CEdit%253A%253ASetReadOnly)%3Bk(SetReadOnly)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#setreadonly).

To quote:

> Specifies whether to set or remove the read-only state of the edit control. A value of `TRUE` sets the state to read-only; a value of `FALSE` sets the state to read/write.

Comment: Hmm.. I am getting this 'SetReadOnly' : is not a member of 'CWnd'
Anything special about this?

Comment: How are you calling it? If you're doing something like GetDlgItem(blah)->SetReadOnly, then you'll probably get an error message like that, because GetDlgItem doesn't return a CEdit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. Is that not the standard way of doing it? What's another way? TIA

Comment: Probably the best way is to use the ClassWizard to set up a member variable for the control or controls you want to change and manipulate the edit control through that. You could probably cast the CWnd* to a CEdit*, but I wouldn't unless you're just out of other options.

Comment: Actually casting CWnd* to CEdit* is idiomatic MFC. Just one of the many reasons it gets no respect.

Answer (score 4):

```
GetDlgItem(blah)->SendMessage(EM_SETREADONLY ,1 ,0);
```

This will set it to read only.

Comment: That's 2 WinApi calls, use SendDlgItemMessage with this flag :)

Comment: Worked like a charm in delphi too.

Answer (score 0):

From the design window:
right-click the edit box, select properties.
Its the last option on the Styles tab.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Setting or removing the read-only flag for an edit control amounts to sending it an [`EM_SETREADONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setreadonly) message. The `wParam` is a boolean value that specifies whether the read-only flag should be set.

There are a few different ways to do this that ultimately do the same thing under the hood:

- If you have a `CEdit`, you can call its [`CEdit::SetReadOnly()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class#setreadonly) member.
- If you have a `CWnd`, you need to send the message explicitly like so:

  ```cpp
  wnd_edit->SendMessage(EM_SETREADONLY, TRUE, 0);
  ```

  Use `FALSE` in place of `TRUE` to remove the read-only flag.
- If you have a bare `HWND` use the Win32 API:

  ```cpp
  ::SendMessage(hwnd_edit, EM_SETREADONLY, TRUE, 0);
  ```

Curiously, there is no dedicated API to query whether an edit control has the read-only flag set. Instead, you have to request the control's style (using [`CWnd::GetStyle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getstyle)) and manually test for the `ES_READONLY` style:

```cpp
auto const is_read_only = (wnd_edit->GetStyle() & ES_READONLY) != 0;
```